# How to set /etc/apt/apt.conf on a Linux subsystem for windows when Windows has automatically proxy setup checked?

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my Windows machine, proxy settings are basic:

```
Automatic Proxy setup:
  Automatically detect settings : checked
```

On my Windows machine, I've installed a Linux subsystem (Ubuntu). I'm trying to perform a `sudo apt update` or a `sudo apt install ...`. Apparently, in order to get this done, I need to fill in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (this file does not exist yet).

I've created that file and very naïvely, I've entered the following:

```
Linux Prompt> cat apt.conf
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy>";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy>";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<proxy>";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks:<proxy>";
```

This, obviously, does not work, and I don't know about any basic proxies, used by my computer, so this leaves me with two possibilities:

- Either I search for a proxy, used by my computer, and I fill it in in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file.
- Either I configure `/etc/apt/apt.conf` in order to detect proxy settings automatically, just like the "parent" Windows machine.

Which of the two options is best and how do I do it?

Thanks

**Edit, some background**

I wanted to do some `sudo apt install` (it's a consequence of [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1663677/how-to-create-a-mounting-point-to-a-shared-drive-from-a-linux-subsystem-on-a-win), but as an example, let's take "emacs-gtk"):

```
Linux Prompt> sudo apt install emacs-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package emacs-gtk
```

When I do a `sudo apt update`:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

As requested: I pinged "8.8.8.8", and there everything seems to be fine:

```
Linux Prompt> ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=9.47 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=9.84 ms
...
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.164/9.388/9.838/0.226 ms
```

I thought that the `apt install` problems were due to the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file (containing the proxy settings), hence my question.

Comment: The fact that your Windows host is set to automatically detect proxy settings is normal - Just about everyone has that option set by default. Since you aren't aware of any proxies you are really using, that's *likely* not your problem. So let's start with the basics - What is the actual problem that you are having?  What error does `sudo apt update` give?  Does other networking from inside WSL break?  Try `ping 8.8.8.8` in WSL - What happens?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: thanks for your quick reply, I added the background of my question (it all starts with `apt install` which doesn't work).

Comment: Ah, based on the error, I can see why you are suspecting proxy.  I seem to recall someone having a similar issue; it might have been on Super User. Away from computer for a few hours, but I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: See if anything in [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/346372/1210833) helps if it really is a proxy issue.